# Neo4J Cypher conditional where statement depending on parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to write a query that takes four parameters which are all lists of ids and which should filter the results.

I have nodes called KnowledgeEntry which have multiple KnowledgeRecords attached to them

```
(:KnowledgeEntry)-[:CONTAINS]->(:KnowledgeRecord)
```

KnowledgeRecords each have four types of relations to nodes of type Location, Community, Function or OrganizationalUnit which all have an id attribute.

I want to retrieve all KnowledgeEntries if they have one or more KnowledgeRecords that have a relation to Location, Community, Function or OU where id matches one of the items in the given list (parameter)

This is what I came up with so far:

```
MATCH (knowledgeEntry:KnowledgeEntry)-[relationship]-(:KnowledgeEntry)
WHERE EXISTS {
    MATCH (knowledgeEntry)-[:CONTAINS]->(:KnowledgeRecord)-[:BASED_AT]->(loc:Location)
    WHERE loc.id IN $filters.locationIds
}

RETURN relationship, knowledgeEntry;
```

This only works if all parameters used are set. If for example $filters.locationIds has no entries or is null the where statement should be ignored. I tried this with CASE statement and apoc.when but had no success.

When adding an OR EXISTS for e.g OrganizationalUnit I get an error "There should be at least one pattern expression"

```
MATCH (knowledgeEntry:KnowledgeEntry)-[relationship]-(:KnowledgeEntry)
WHERE EXISTS {
    MATCH (knowledgeEntry)-[:CONTAINS]->(:KnowledgeRecord)-[:BASED_AT]->(loc:Location)
    WHERE loc.id IN $locationIds
}

OR EXISTS {
    MATCH (knowledgeEntry)-[:CONTAINS]->(:KnowledgeRecord)-[:RELEVANT_FOR_EMPLOYEES_WITH]->(ou:OrganizationalUnit)
    WHERE ou.id IN $organizationalUnitIds
}

RETURN relationship, knowledgeEntry;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are encountering a possible neo4j bug when there are multiple [existential subqueries](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/where/#existential-subqueries) in a boolean expression.

This query combines your two subqueries, and may work better for you:

```
MATCH (knowledgeEntry:KnowledgeEntry)-[relationship]-(:KnowledgeEntry)
WHERE EXISTS {
  MATCH (knowledgeEntry)-[:CONTAINS]->(:KnowledgeRecord)-[:BASED_AT|RELEVANT_FOR_EMPLOYEES_WITH]->(x)
  WHERE
    (x:OrganizationalUnit AND x.id IN $organizationalUnitIds) OR
    (x:Location AND x.id IN $locationIds)
}
RETURN relationship, knowledgeEntry;
```